# Get the first day of every week until infinity in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, react-hooks, babeljs

I want a program that can generate the date of first date of every week, so that I can insert it into the code below

```
const dateOfTheFirstDay = null;

//preferred format: "April 9, 2023 00:00:01"

const d = new Date(dateOfTheFirstDay);
  setNewWeekTime(d.getTime());
```

From the code above, I can then get the milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00 and the first date of the week.

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Preffered format :"April 9, 2023 00:00:01" - date of every Sunday

Comment: so, you want to get every Sunday in the current year? whats the limits? There should be limits anyway.

Comment: yes, date of every sunday of the year 2023, lets limit it to 2023

Comment: You know that Sundays are 7 days apart right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here could be the code to achieve your request in javascript

```
const startDate = new Date('January 1, 2023');
const endDate = new Date('December 31, 2023');
const days = ['Sunday'];
const sundayDates = [];

for (let date = startDate; date <= endDate; date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)) {
   if (days.includes(date.toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' }))) {
        sundayDates.push(new Date(date));
   }
}
```

`sundayDates` array will give you the dates you wish

Comment: `new Date('January 1, 2023')` is a poor way to initialise a *Date*, consider `new Date(2023, 0,1 )`.  Looping over every single date and weeding out Sundays using *toLocaleString* is extremely inefficient. The first Sunday on or before the reference date is given by `date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay())`. Every subsequent Sunday is given by adding 7 days.

Answer (score 2):

Since any given day of the week is guaranteed to be 7 days apart you really just need to find an initial reference date and then increment by multiples of 7 either forward or backward. Keep in mind that you will need to decide how to handle timezone issues.

Here is a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) based solution that will yield any given day forwards from 1583 (to avoid wierdness of dates before adoption of the Gregorian calendar, see [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)).

```js
function* dayGenerator(day) {
  const addDays = (date, days) => date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + days);

  const ref = new Date(Date.UTC(1583, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0));
  while (ref.toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' }) !== day) {
    addDays(ref, 1);
  }

  yield new Date(ref);

  while (true) {
    yield new Date(addDays(ref, 7));
  }
}


/* Example output */

// The first 10,000 Sundays from Jan 1, 1583
console.log('Sundays:');
const sundayGenerator = dayGenerator('Sunday');
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  const next = sundayGenerator.next().value;
  if (i <= 3 || i === 9999) {
    console.log(
      `Sunday ${i + 1}:`,
      next,
      next.toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' })
    );
  }
}

// A few Tuesdays
console.log('Tuesdays:');
const tuesdayGenerator = dayGenerator('Tuesday');
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const next = tuesdayGenerator.next().value;
  console.log(next, next.toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' }));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row::after { display: none !important; }
```

You can make it generic by accepting a `startDate` and `endDate` and could further customize to increment backwards if `start > end`. Here using an alternative arithmetic based method for determining the first matching day *after* the passed start date.

```js
function* dayGenerator(
  day,
  startDateISO = '1583-01-01T12:00:00.000Z',
  endDateISO = '9999-12-31T12:00:00.000Z'
) {
  const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday',];

  const ref = new Date(startDateISO);
  ref.setDate(ref.getDate() + ((7 + days.indexOf(day) - ref.getDay()) % 7));

  yield new Date(ref);

  const endDate = new Date(endDateISO);
  while (ref < endDate) {
    yield new Date(ref.setDate(ref.getDate() + 7));
  }
}

// Spread the full output of the iterator into an array
const sundays2023 = [
  ...dayGenerator('Sunday', '2023-01-01T12:00:00Z', '2023-12-31T12:00:00Z'),
];

console.log(
  'First: ',
  sundays2023[0],
  sundays2023[0].toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' })
);
console.log(
  'Last: ',
  sundays2023.at(-1),
  sundays2023.at(-1).toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' })
);
```

*(curiously 2023 starts and ends on a Sunday)*

Comment: Perhaps you mistook how generators work? The initial `while` in mine only runs on the first call of the generator and at most for `6` iterations to find the first matching day. After that it is simply yielding the reference date incremented by 7. `yield new Date(ref.setDate(ref.getDate() + 7))`.

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed too quickly. :-(

Answer (score 1):

An efficient algorithm to get an array of Sundays between two dates is to get the Sunday on or before a reference date, then sequentially add 7 days until the end date is reached.

The following gets all Sundays for the year of the supplied date, with the current date (and hence year) as the default.

E.g.

```js
// Return an array of all Sundays in year of
// supplied date
function getSundaysInYear(date = new Date()){
  // Get first Sunday of year
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  let start = new Date(year, 0, 7);
  start.setDate(start.getDate() - start.getDay());
  // Set last date of year
  let end = new Date(year, 11, 31);
  // Array of Sundays
  let sundays = [];

  while (start <= end) {
    sundays.push(new Date(start));
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 7);
  }
  return sundays
}

// Example
let d = new Date()
let sundays = getSundaysInYear(d);
console.log(`${d.getFullYear()} has ${sundays.length} Sundays.` +
  `\nFirst: ${sundays[0].toString().substr(0,10)} ` +
  `\nLast : ${sundays[sundays.length - 1].toString().substr(0,10)}`
);
```